# UNIX shell-scripting: Split a textfile by its entries

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to analyze an enormous text file (1.6GB), whose data lines look like this:

```
20090118025859 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090118025900 -2.500000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090118025901 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
```

I don't even know how many lines there are. But I'm trying to split the file by date. The left number is a time stamp (these lines for example are from 2009, january 18th).
How can I split this file into pieces according to the date?

The number of entries per date differs, so using `split` with a constant number won't work.
Everything I know would be to `grep file '20090118*' > data20090118.dat` , but there sure is a way to do all the dates at once, right?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{print  > "data"substr($1,0,8)".dat"}' myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if the items are in date sequence:

```
date=20090101 # Change to the earliest date
while IFS= read -rd $'\n' line
do
    if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -c 1-8)" -eq $date ]
    then
        echo "$line" >> "$date.dat"
    else
        let date++
    fi
done < log.dat
```

Comment: Doesn't work also because of the spaces around the equal sign. The default delimiter for `read` is already newline. Instead of setting the earliest date and incrementing by one, just check to see if the date in the current line is equal to the previous date saved. When it changes, change the saved value.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveats that each day needs to have more than 1 record,
and that the output file will have blank lines:

```
uniq --all-repeated=separate -w8 file | csplit -s - '/^$/' '{*}'
```

We really should have an option to uniq to output even uniq records.
Also csplit should have an option to suppress the matched line.